# How to sign commited group elements?

Tags: signature, pairings, commitments

I'm actually searching some particular primitive compatible with Groth-Sahai commitment.

I would like to know a signature scheme (on group elements), such that there exists an algorithm $\mathtt{SigCom}$ such that it takes as input the commitment key $\mathtt{ck}$ , the signing key $\mathtt{sk}$ and a commitment $\mathtt{c}$ and outputs a committed signature $\mathtt{c}_\sigma$ with a (Groth-Sahai) proof $\pi$ that certifies the signature committed is the signature of the value (in the commitment of the input).

I've found [this article](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/320.pdf).
It does exactly what I want except that the value are on a precise type $\left(G^m, H^m\right)$, and it's too restrictive for me.

If you know a more general result (or something that fit with two group elements without any relation between them), it would be good for me.

Comment: see this paper aswell: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-14623-7_12

It has the same message space so it might still be too restrictive though. Maybe you could clarify your restrictions?

Comment: I would like to have something very general which can consider each vector of group elements as message.

Comment: Without having studied the details of the paper I linked, it does not seem that any party actually has to know neither $m$ nor $H^m$, which should then satisfy your requirements. Also, the authors state that the scheme can be instantiated for $G_1 = G_2$, which seems in line with your general setting.

Comment: $H$ is fixed, then only few vectors can be signed. For example $(G, H^2)$ can't be signed.

Comment: you are not actually signing $H^m$ in section 4 of the linked paper, the value only exists. But instead, have a look at section 5 of the linked paper. It proposes a scheme for signing vectors of group elements, which seems to be what you need

Comment: Yes, but then, there is no more $Sigcom$, as far as I understood.

Comment: The paper presents a commitment scheme for committing to group elements, and a signature scheme where the signature is a group element. Composing this into a "SigCom" should be trivial. But perhaps that is not what you mean?

Comment: No, because, $Sigcom$ takes as input a commitment, then it's not a simple composition.

Comment: But since the commitment is a group element, that should befine. What is the problem?

Comment: Because it should output a commitment of a signature of the message committed. Even we do not have access to this message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127058/discussion-between-joakimb-and-ievgeni).

Answer (score 0):

The paper [Structure-Preserving Signatures and Commitments to Group Elements](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-14623-7_12) presents a commitment scheme for committing to (vectors of) group elements, and a signature scheme which outputs signatures (on vectors of group elements) as group elements. Composing these two should be straightforward for your needs.

Comment: No, because, Sigcom takes as input a commitment, then it's not a simple composition.